# Custom email branding in AD B2C

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

Is there an ability to customize email messages that are sent from b2clogin.com during email verification flows? It seems like we can control the color, tenant name, and add a logo, but that's about it. Would love to be able to make the message body truly look more like our own branding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Custom email verification requires the use of a third-party email provider like SendGrid or SparkPost, a custom REST API, or any HTTP-based email provider (including your own). Please refer the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/custom-email)

Note: This Feature is currently in Public Preview.